# Get disk_used_percent metrics for specific PATH with CloudWatch Agent

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

```
{
  "agent": {
    "run_as_user": "root"
  },
  "metrics": {
      "disk": {
        "measurement": [
          "used_percent"
        ],
        "metrics_collection_interval": 60,
        "resources": [
          "/media/mysql-data","/","/tmp", "/usr", "/media"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

results in only
[image]

I haven't found any examples of folks including a specific path in the `resources` section of a `amazon-cloudwatch-agent/bin/config.json` file to monitor the `disk_used_percent`. When I specify only one specific path, like `/media/mysql-data` and put files in it, or if I make `/media/mysql-data` be a file, no `disk_used_percent` metrics appear in CloudWatch. The only one that appears is `/`.

I'm trying to convert our use of the [old monitoring scripts](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/monitoring-scripts-intro.html#using_get_script_powershell) to the CloudWatch Agent configuration file, in particular, the options `--disk-space-util --disk-path=/media/mysql-data`

The documentation for that option says:

> `--disk-path=PATH` Selects the disk on which to report.

> `PATH` can specify a mount point or any file located on a mount point for the filesystem that needs to be reported. For selecting multiple disks, specify a -`-disk-path=PATH` for each one of them.

> To select a disk for the filesystems mounted on `/` and `/home`, use the following parameters:

> `--disk-path=/ --disk-path=/home`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got the answer from AWS Support. As it says in [the docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/CloudWatch-Agent-Configuration-File-Details.html),

> `disk` – Optional. Specifies that disk metrics are to be collected. This section is valid only for Linux instances. This section can include as many as two fields:

> `resources` – Optional. Specifies an array of disk mount points. This field limits CloudWatch to collect metrics from only the listed mount points. You can specify * as the value to collect metrics from all mount points. The default value is to collect metrics from all mount points.

In other words, the path specified must be a mount point for this to work. So to see all the paths available to be monitored, I can just run `lsblk`.